# Best way to blog while locally editing files?

Tags: dropbox, markdown, blogging

I want to blog while editing my files locally.

Requirements:

1. Edit the files *locally only* (on my computer, using my text editor), in some clean format (say, Markdown).
2. Have the files viewable online anywhere (don't care about the link) in some decent format (say, HTML made from the markdown).

I have not found any decent solution for this: Wordpress.com does not properly format markdown (and does not sync with local computer), Dropbox displays files as .md without formatting into HTML, Medium does not allow .md, extensions such as Calepin, Scriptogram, Markbox.io and so on have all failed me.

I would assume this to be a common use-case - people who want to blog and display decently pretty posts online, but write/edit the files locally. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Octopress.org is your solution. It runs locally, and uploads the website to either Github, your own server, or you can publish the files to a Dropbox folder if you want.

It uses Jekyll, but Jekyll is hardcore.

Comment: Octopress looks good, but I've spent a couple hours fighting with its tutorial and I can't even get a decent Hello-World on Github pages. I am very comfortable with Git, but I don't understand what it's trying to do with my github pages and I end up with a broken blog (http://sellarafaeli.github.io/sellarafaeli/github/ ? or http://sellarafaeli.github.io/ ?)/. Any thoughts?

Comment: I mean, I don't understand the deploy process for new posts at all. Am I supposed to push to git? Or run rake deploy? Or both? When do I run rake generate?

Going step by step as appears http://octopress.org/docs/setup/ has not resulted in anything viewable. Trying to hack around it and inspect what it's doing has made minimal (costly) progress. Is there perhaps another tutorial you could recommend?

Comment: I have to go to a function now. I'm just getting myself ready. When I get back home, I will dummy up a step-by-step for you so you can publish it to GitHub.

Octopress doesn't have the most useable instructions for first time users. I use it religiously on a VPN. I used to use it on GitHub too. I will help you out when I get home today. :-)

Comment: That would be awesome, I'd appreciate that. You should publish the step-by-step to the world :)

Answer (score 0):

[ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/) is another alternative that does all that. The hosting is up to you, though there is a semi-official host in [Branchable](https://www.branchable.com/). ikiwiki generates static pages that can be hosted anywhere.

ikiwiki is built around version control systems, primarily Git (it is usable with other systems, but [not with all bells and whistles](http://ikiwiki.info/rcs/)) . It is a nice fit for a blogging/wiki platform to have the VCS integrated in the content generation.

It is open and configurable down to every bit. It is built with Perl, but as an end user there is no need to see any Perl unless one wants to extend or modify existing base code or plugins.